# How to calculate $\sum\frac{1}{(4k-1)(4k+4)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(4k-1)(4k+4)}$ using telescopic sums. I've already proved this equality: $\sum\frac{1}{(4k-1)(4k+4)}=\frac{1}{5}\big(\sum\frac{1}{4k-1}-\frac{1}{4k+4}\big)$. The problem is I can't cancel the terms of this sum.

I need help

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason to think you can turn this into a telescoping sum?  Seems difficult. You might be able to turn it into a sum of logarithms.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The book I'm using suggested to use telescopic sums.

Comment: According to Wolfram, the solution is $\frac{1}{40}(2-\pi + \log(64))$. Given that, I have upvoted you because I am curious how an answer like that is going to arise from a telescoping sum.

Comment: the sum can be expressed as $\frac{-\psi (-1/4)-\gamma }{20}$ where $\psi $ is the digamma function and $\gamma $ is the Euler constant

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:  $S=\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} S_n=\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\dfrac{1}{4k-1} - \dfrac{1}{4k+4}\right) = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \left(\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n\left(x^{4k-2} - x^{4k+3}\right)\right)dx= \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \left(x^{4k-2} - x^{4k+3}\right)dx$. Can you compute the integrand, and integrate it.

Comment: Aren't we looping in such a case ?

Comment: I've done this before and even asked a question like it before and was sure it can be done this way, and unlikely loop.