# Finding the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {2 \over (4n-1)(4n+3)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know this is very similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032479/evaluation-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac14n-3-frac14n-1), so I thought the answer should be $\frac \pi 4$ until I saw [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213806/how-to-calculate-sum-frac14k-14k4?rq=1) that is more like mine that doesn't have a good answer (or if it is I am having trouble understanding it), but it is 2 years old so I don't think it will be getting another answer soon.

Anyway, I was able to prove that this sum converges by the direct comparison test to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac 1 {n^2}}$ (thanks to the help in my previous question), but now to find the sum.

I tried to use partial sums

$${2 \over (4n-1)(4n+3)} = {2 \over 19(4n-1)} - {1 \over 2(4n+3)}.$$

If this is right I think I am stuck since $19(4n-1)$ is always odd, but $2(4n+3)$ is always even so telescoping won't work unless I am mistaken.

Comment: `I tried to use partial sums` Not a bad idea, but doublecheck your calculations there.

Comment: It should have been $\frac{2}{(4n-1)(4n+3)}=\frac{1}{2(4n-1)}-\frac{1}{2(4n+3)}$

Comment: you made a mistake in computing partial fractions

Comment: Wow, I apologize to the community this was not a good question. I will make sure to check my work before I post from now on

Comment: You may check your work using [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave) [online](https://octave-online.net/).  I've just read the [manual page for polynomial operations](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Products-of-Polynomials.html) and find out that your problem can be solve by typing `[r,p,k,e] = residue(2, conv([4 -1][4 +3]))`, which means that your are finding the partial fraction expression for the numerator $2$ divided by the product of $4n-1$ and $4n+3$.  This gives a sum of fractions $\dfrac{r(i)}{(n - p(i))^{e(i)}}$ and a polynomial `k`, where $i$ is array index.

Comment: @GNUSupporter That is a good idea; I will try that in the future.

Comment: Typo: `[r,p,k,e] = residue(2, conv([4 -1],[4 +3]))`  I missed a comma `,`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{1/2}{4n-1} - \frac{1/2}{4n+3} = \frac{2}{(4n-1)(4n+3)}$$
Hence your sum is telescoping
$$\frac{1/2}{3} - \frac{1/2}{7} + \frac{1/2}{7} - \frac{1/2}{11} + \frac{1/2}{11} - \frac{1/2}{15} + \cdots$$
and it's clear that the sum is $\frac{1}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **trick** to find those **fractions** with little effort ( i will post here in a more general form )

If we have only two terms in the denominator
$$\frac{1}{(ak+b)(ak+b+a) }=\frac{1}{a}\frac{(ak+b+a) -(ak+b)}{(ak+b)(ak+b+a) }$$
$$=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{(ak+b) } -\frac{1}{sa}\frac{1}{ (ak+b+a) }. $$

**A still more general case:**
Calculate the sum
$$\sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{1}{(ak+b)(ak+b+a)\ldots (ak+b+sa) }. $$

Every time we have this kind of summation we can use the telescoping sum. To find the terms of telescoping sum  we can  add in the numerator the following difference:  $(ak+b+sa)$ `the greatest term" minus the`lowest term" $(ak+b)$, and to not alter the fraction divide by $\frac{1}{sa}$  (which is the resultant  difference  of those terms).
$$\frac{1}{(ak+b)(ak+b+a)\ldots (ak+b+sa) }=\frac{1}{sa}\frac{(ak+b+sa) -(ak+b)}{(ak+b)(ak+b+a)\ldots (ak+b+sa) }$$
$$=\frac{1}{sa}\frac{1}{(ak+b)(ak+b+a)\ldots (ak+b+(s-1)a) } -\frac{1}{sa}\frac{1}{(ak+b+a)\ldots (ak+b+sa) }. $$

Take $f(k)=\frac{1}{sa}\frac{1}{(ak+b)(ak+b+a)\ldots (ak+b+(s-1)a) }.$
Then the sum is
$$\frac{-1}{sa}\sum^{n}_{k=0} \left(f(k+1) -f(k)\right) $$
by the telescopic sum it's
$$=\frac{-1}{sa}\left(f(n+1) -f(0)\right)=\frac{-1}{sa}\left(\frac{1}{(an+b)\ldots (an+b+(s-1)a) } -\frac{1}{(b)(b+a)\ldots (+b+(s-1)a) }\right). $$

Comment: Thank you for this interesting trick. Although I don't think I am good enough to use this yet, I am sure that others will find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you, i hope it could help somebody xD
In the case of your question the trick to find the partial fractions is
$$\frac{1}{(4n-1)(4n+3)}=\frac{(4n+3)-(4n-1)}{4(4n-1)(4n+3)}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{4n+3}{(4n-1)(4n+3)} - \frac{1}{4}\frac{(4n-1)}{(4n-1)(4n+3)} $$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{(4n-1)} - \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{(4n+3)}. $$

So multiplying by $2$ you have the decomposition
$$\frac{2}{(4n-1)(4n+3)}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(4n-1)} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(4n+3)}. $$